# Database drop table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

If I have a `select t.name as tableName from sys.tables t`... How can I drop all those tables? I mean I have them, but I want to do something like...

```
drop table where tableName in select t.name as tableName from sys.tables t
```

An option would be with C# to create and run some SP? Any ideea?

Comment: Is this as a one off or does this form part of a process?

Comment: you need to either use dynamic sql or create the sql statements outside of sql server (c# in your case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example script.  Use with caution.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL += N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name) + N';
'
FROM sys.tables
<include your where clause here>

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Had to adjust it just a little for my needs but it was just what I was thinking of. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In C# you could build a code like this. 
First execute the SELECT to fill a datatable with the table names, then use the StringBuilder class to build a batch command with all the DROP required.

**Strongly suggest to have a backup before runnning this code.....**

```
string cmdText = "select t.name as tableName from sys.tables t";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
connection.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
string baseCmd = "DROP TABLE {0};\r\n";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
   sb.AppendFormat(baseCmd, r["tableName"].ToString());

cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    IF OBJECT_ID(''' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';
    '
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE [type] = 'U'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```